# How to remove add-in using REST API in office add-in for outlook or event handler for when user removes add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have a use case to receive call-back event when user removes add-in from outlook or need to remove add-in using REST API. can any guide ?

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide any callback or events for that. Feature requests on `Tech Community` are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: See [Deploy and install Outlook add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/testing-and-tips) for more information.

Comment: Confirming that this is the correct answer. However, can you describe your scenario, and what you are trying to accomplish to help us understand what gaps might be missing in the API or if there is another workaround?